# Node.js JSON to XML - serialize a complex object

Tags: node.js, xml

I'm attempting to convert a complex JSON object to XML using [this package - XML](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml).

```
 var xml = require("xml");
 var obj = {  MS : { ts : 3423523, isOk : false , errors : [] }};
 var xmlObj = xml(obj); //  This outputs <MS/>
```

Any ideas how to make the XML parser go deeper? Why is it prematurely closed?

Comment: *"Values can be an array of xmlObjects or a value such as a string or number."* - not an object.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so any why to serialize a complex object, I can iterate over it myself i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give the [xml2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js) module a try, this would convert your object to Xml quite easily, e.g.

```
const xml2js = require('xml2js');

const obj = {  MS : { ts : 3423523, isOk : false , errors : [] }};

const builder = new xml2js.Builder( { headless: false, renderOpts: { pretty: true }  });
const xml = builder.buildObject(obj);

console.log(xml)
```

The output would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<MS>
  <ts>3423523</ts>
  <isOk>false</isOk>
</MS>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this later on